# Getting null values on POST resquest with strapi deployed on heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, post, backend, strapi

I am making a little web agenda where the user would be able to write homework and read which is written each day. The web it's written in HTML, CSS and Vanilla JS. I have Strapi as a backend and I have deployed it to Heroku using its documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/heroku.html#_6-install-the-pg-node-module

I have no problem with GET requests, but when I try to make a POST request I get null values on the attributes of my content-type. This is my code (it's based on https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#create-an-entry):

```
function registerHomework(){
    var s = document.getElementById("subject").value
    var h = document.getElementById("homework").value
    var t = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

    fetch('https://agenda-back.herokuapp.com/api/homeworks', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "data": {
                "id": i,
                "attributes": {subject: `${s}`, homework: `${h}`, date: `${t}`}
            }
             
        })
    })
}
```

This is the response I get:

```
data: {
    id: 8,
    subject: 'null',
    homework: 'null',
    date: 'null',
    created_at: '2022-11-16T12:12:57.078Z',
    updated_at: '2022-11-16T12:12:57.078Z'
  }
```

I don't know why it does not register the attributes. I was thinking that it had something to do with permisions, but I have changed the content-type public role in strapi: now anyone should be able to create an entry. I still get the same `null` value.

I also found this: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5958 but I'm not using `axios`. I don't know if it is posible make a POST request from the frontend directly (I understand from the strapi docs that it is), but maybe I am not understanding it correctly. Maybe it's some authorization issue even that I selected that a public user can create an entry?

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the docs you linked, you are not allowed to use the attributes key to send data. You can send data directly.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "subject": "Hello",
    "homework": "Test",
    "date": "2022-11-17",
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't realize about that after all the modifications I made. It worked!